# RuntimeException: Failed to execute Page Indexer Request

Tags: php, solr, permissions, typo3, runtimeexception

I have configured solr on my Typo3 web site successfully, but The indexing works fine for news but not for pages.

I get this error :

```
Manual Indexing An error occurred while indexing manual from the backend.
```

When I click on Show error, I found this error :

```
1319116885: RuntimeException: Failed to execute Page Indexer Request. See log for details. Request ID: 5d728d6969ccf in /var/www/mysite.com/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/IndexQueue/PageIndexerRequest.php:219
```

My config :

```
EXT: solr : 9.0.2

Solr Apache : 7.6.0

TYPO3 : 9.5.3

http
```

Comment: So what does the referenced "See log for details" show? Does the Solr server log show anything?

Comment: I share the log : https://www.codepile.net/pile/nNo2n5PM

Comment: Please add the relevant parts from the log to your question; your link is the stack trace of the triggered error, not the actual log referenced as far as I know.

Comment: I check the log file and nothing related to solr, I enabled the `plugin.tx_solr.logging.debugOutput = 1` and the error is `DevLog ext:solr: Failed to execute Page Indexer Request. Request ID: 5d765d0730aaa
DevLog ext:solr: Failed indexing Index Queue item 23885`

Comment: What does the Solr log show?

Comment: I share with you screenshots : 1. Error when "Index now" : https://i.ibb.co/6W4gNZb/1-solr.jpg / 2. Error when "Show error" : https://i.ibb.co/bNXbRC9/2-solr.jpg / 3. Solr server Log : https://i.ibb.co/f1krSqn/3-solr.jpg / 4. log when run Scheduled task : https://i.ibb.co/287MkVt/4-solr.jpg

Comment: Logs should always be added to the question itself and any images should be hosted using Stack Overflows own image host (through imgur), so they're kept together with the post itself. In your Solr log it shows that there's a request that references a field named `type` that fails. If this occurs because of attempting to index a document, there seems to be missing fields in your Solr schema that Typo expects to be there.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem come from schema.xml file, beacause I get this error `Unsupported Schema A schema different from the one provided with the extension was detected.` and `Your Solr server is currently using schema version default-config, the recommended schema version is tx_solr-9-0-0--20180727.` How can I switch from default-config to tx_solr-9-0-0--20180727 ?

Comment: That sounds like the schema bundled with Typo. Check the documentation for the extension on how to install the proper schema.